# Print a new column with conditional contraints using if statement in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, if-statement

I have a table 'actor' whose fields are 'pk','fname',lname.
I want to print a column(lets call this name) where by default fname is printed but if fname is null then lname is printed.

The query that I used is:

```
select if(fname = null,lname,fname) as name from actor;
```

This however does not achieve the given task.
It prints the fname even if the value is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare with `NULL` value you need to use [`IS NULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_is-null):

```
select if(fname IS NULL,lname,fname) as name from actor;
```

or [`<=>`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal-to):

```
select if(fname <=> null,lname,fname) as name from actor;
```

---

In your example the easiest way is to use [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT COALESCE(fname, lname) AS name FROM actor;
```